# What mean extra=101 information in rpart plot?

Tags: r, rpart

What mean each number with slashes between them (my plot) when is used the parameter extra=101, the documenttion said "Display the number of observations that fall in the node (per class for class objects; prefixed by the number of events for poisson and exp models)", but this is not clear for me.

How I can interpret them in my plot?

[image: Tree]

What mean the first number position and always represent the same? What mean the second number position and always represent the same? What mean the last number position and always represent the same?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the code you used to generate this plot? It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: prp(mod.dt, 
    extra=101, 
    under=T, 
    faclen=0, 
    type=0, 
    nn.col=1, 
    yesno=T, 
    xsep="/", 
    prefix="Class ")

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the [vignette] link for more information:
 https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rpart.plot/rpart.plot.pdf

extra=101 displays the number and percentage of observations
in the node. Actually, it’s a weighted percentage using the weights
passed to rpart.